# How do I get tag as text in javascript, without using outerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

What I want is outerHTML without innerHTML.

I don't want to compute string of innerHTML, as it might be expensive and I've to do this operation frequently, is there a simple way to get it?

Comment: Example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Can't you just use the DOM?  Everything is available, assuming you use document.getElementById, then verify the return is an object and then dereference the returned node to get .parentNode .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the elements' internals and build the string yourself from that:

```js
function getTagHTML(el) {
  if (!el instanceof HTMLElement) return null;
  let result = `<${el.tagName.toLowerCase()}`;
  for (const attribute in el.attributes) {
    if (el.attributes[attribute].nodeValue) 
      result += ` ${el.attributes[attribute].name}="${el.attributes[attribute].nodeValue.replace(/"/g, "&quot;")}"`
  }
  result += `></${el.tagName.toLowerCase()}>`;
  return result;
}

console.log(getTagHTML(document.getElementById('outer')));
```

```html
<div id="outer" class='i-want-"this"'>
  <span>I do not want this</span>
</div>
```

If the opening tag is enough, that's easy:

```js
const tag = `${outer.outerHTML.split('>')[0]}>`;

console.log(tag);
```

```html
<div id="outer" class="i-want-this">
  <span>I do not want this</span>
</div>
```

Please note, that as pointed out by Quentin, the `>` cannot be relied upon to mark the end of the opening tag as it may very well occur within any attribute's value.

Comment: That's unreliable. You can't depend on the first `>` character being the end of the start tag. e.g.: https://jsbin.com/liqarigiju/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: That doesn't seem properly encoded. Wouldn't it have to be `3 &gt; 2`?

Comment: No. `>` characters don't have special meaning inside an attribute value (at least if it is quoted) and don't need to be expressed as an entity. If the HTML was written with an entity, then you'd get the same result because the browser would normalize it when converting the DOM back to HTML via `outerHTML`. https://jsbin.com/tatuhutixa/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: @Quentin Thx for pointing out, will edit that into my post accordingly. Added a more robust way that won't rely on String parsing.

Comment: Re edit: `el.attributes[attribute].nodeValue` needs escaping. It might contain `"` characters.

Comment: @Quentin what if those are escaped already using `\"`?

Comment: ```\``` isn't an escape character in HTML

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know there is no JavaScript "native" way to get the HTML Tag without its' content. How about using jQuery and

```
let oElement = $("#myElementsID");
```

or

```
let oElement = $(".myElementsClass");
```

That won't give you the HTML tag, but all the information that you could ask for in a neat object.